# What alternative to `os.walk` will throw StopIteration only if it has visited every directory in the tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath, hierarchy

`os.walk` returns an iterator which is meant to visit every directory in some tree. I want something like `os.walk` which will throw `StopIteration` (or something to that effect) ***if and only if*** every directory in the tree has been visited.

`os.walk` throws `StopIteration` when every directory in a tree as been visited ***or*** some error is encountered along the way. For example, consider the following print-out and error message:

```
checking for empty folders under F:\

checking for empty folders under F:\$RECYCLE.BIN

checking for empty folders under F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/DRIVER.PY", line 228, in remove_empty_dirs
    directories = next(os.walk(cur))[1]
StopIteration
```

My `F:\` drive has thousands of directories and files. There is no way that all of them were visited.

Caveat: I did not make `F:\` the root the the walk.
`F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18` is the root of the walk. As such, the iterator will never go "up" above `F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18`

At first, I thought that `F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18` was empty, and so, `F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18` was the ***last*** directory under the tree rooted at `F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18`

However, `next(os.walk(path_to_an_empty_directory))` does ***NOT*** throw `StopIteration`

```
import os
import pathlib
import shutil

if True:
   path = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "I_am_a_directory"
   if path.is_dir():
       shutil.rmtree(path)
   os.mkdir(path)
   print(next(os.walk(path))[0])
   print("os.walk did not raise ", StopIteration.__name__)
```

---

### EDIT:

My code looks something like this:

```
import os
import pathlib

def take_a_walk(xpath):

    ipath = pathlib.Path(str(xpath))

    print(''.join(str(x) for x in [
        "VISITED ", str(ipath)
    ]))

    children = next(os.walk(ipath))[1]
    children = [ipath / child for child in children]
    for child in children:
        take_a_walk(child)
    return "Fahrvergnugen"

take_a_walk('F:\\')
```

Comment: it doesn't throw StopIteration for empty folder because when you run `next()` this folder is still not-visited. After `next()` this folder is visited and next `next()` will raise error. But before second `next()` it still doesn't know that all folders were visited.

Comment: you can do `print("VISITED {}".format(ipath))`. For Python 3.6+ you can even do `print(f"VISITED {ipath}")`. There is no need to convert strings to strings again.

Comment: I don't know why you get `StopIteration` in code. I have only idea that you removed folder before `os.walk` visited it - so it couldn't get information about files in this folder. If you delete folders then delete them after visiting by `os.walk` or get all folders at start - `list(os.walk())` and later check if folder still exist before you do something with this folder. But I never tested this method. Using `os.walk()` with `for` or `next()` would get more actuall information about folder.

Comment: @furas My code does not delete any folders; it only visits them.

Comment: if you don't delete folders then `os.walk` should raise `StopIteration` only when it visited all folders. If there is other problem then I would expect different  error. But in documentation for [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) you can see option `onerror` and you can assign function which will be executed when there is any `OSError`. If this is not enought then you will have to write own function for this.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need an alternative to `os.walk` per-se, we simply need to assign an argument to the `onerror` parameter.

By default, if an error is encountered while inspecting a path, the iterator returned by `os.walk` will skip the current path, and move onto the next path.

```
def r(err):
    raise err

os.walk(path, onerror=r)
```